# Function parameter passing in a Linux kernel interrupt handler (from asm to C)

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, interrupt-handling, calling-convention

When I read the Linux kernel source, I came across this piece of code:

```
__visible void __irq_entry smp_apic_timer_interrupt(struct pt_regs *regs)   
{
    struct pt_regs *old_regs = set_irq_regs(regs);

    entering_ack_irq();
    local_apic_timer_interrupt();
    exiting_irq();

    set_irq_regs(old_regs);
}
```

The function `smp_apic_timer_interrupt()` takes one parameter. The calling of this function is by a piece of assembly language code:

```
ENTRY(apic_timer_interrupt)
     RING0_INT_FRAME;     
     ASM_CLAC;           
     pushl_cfi $~(0xef);
     SAVE_ALL;         
     TRACE_IRQS_OFF
     movl %esp,%eax;
     call smp_apic_timer_interrupt; // <------call high level C function       
     jmp ret_from_intr;      
     CFI_ENDPROC;           
ENDPROC(apic_timer_interrupt)
```

I cannot figure out how the high level *C* function `smp_apic_timer_interrupt()` get its parameter (by which register)?

Answer (score 10):

Your are probably thinking normal calling convention (arguments on the stack). Modern Linux kernels (32-bit variants) pass the first 3 parameters in registers (*EAX*, *EDX*, *ECX*, in that order) as an optimization. Depending on the kernel this convention is specified as an attribute modifier on the functions using `__attribute__(regparm(3))`, or modern versions of the kernel pass `-mregparm=3` option to *GCC* on the command line. The *GCC* [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) says this about that option/attribute:

> ```
> regparm (number)
> ```

```
On the Intel 386, the regparm attribute causes the compiler to pass up to
number integer arguments in registers EAX, EDX, and ECX instead of on the
stack. Functions that take a variable number of arguments will continue to
be passed all of their arguments on the stack.
```

> 

In ancient kernels the normal 32-bit ABI (and convention of arguments on the stack) was the norm. Eventually the kernel configuration supported arguments in registers *OR* the normal stack convention via the *CONFIG_REGPARM* setting in the kernel build configuration:

> ```
> config REGPARM
> ```

```
    bool "Use register arguments"
    default y
    help
    Compile the kernel with -mregparm=3. This instructs gcc to use
    a more efficient function call ABI which passes the first three
    arguments of a function call via registers, which results in denser
    and faster code.
```

> 

```
    If this option is disabled, then the default ABI of passing
    arguments via the stack is used.
```

> 

```
    If unsure, say Y.
```

> 

The Linux kernel maintainers got rid of this option in 2006 with this [kernel commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a1a70c25bed75ed36ed48bbe18b9029428d2452d):

> ```
> -mregparm=3 has been enabled by default for some time on i386, and AFAIK
> ```

```
there aren't any problems with it left.
```

> 

```
This patch removes the REGPARM config option and sets -mregparm=3
unconditionally.
```

> 

Based on this knowledge one can look at the code you have presented and assume we are on a kernel where it has defaulted to the first 3 parameters being passed in registers. In your case:

```
 __visible void __irq_entry smp_apic_timer_interrupt(struct pt_regs *regs)
```

has *one* parameter so it is passed in *EAX* . The code that called *smp_apic_timer_interrupt* looked like this:

```
ENTRY(apic_timer_interrupt)
     RING0_INT_FRAME;     
     ASM_CLAC;           
     pushl_cfi $~(0xef);
     SAVE_ALL;         
     TRACE_IRQS_OFF
     movl %esp,%eax;
     call smp_apic_timer_interrupt; // <------call high level C function       
     jmp ret_from_intr;      
     CFI_ENDPROC;           
ENDPROC(apic_timer_interrupt)
```

The important part is that the [SAVE_ALL](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.3#L194) macro call pushes all the required registers on the stack. It will vary from version to version of the kernel, but the main effect of pushing registers on the stack is similar (I've removed the *DWARF* entries for brevity):

```
.macro SAVE_ALL
         cld
         PUSH_GS
         pushl_cfi %fs
         pushl_cfi %es
         pushl_cfi %ds
         pushl_cfi %eax
         pushl_cfi %ebp
         pushl_cfi %edi
         pushl_cfi %esi
         pushl_cfi %edx
         pushl_cfi %ecx
         pushl_cfi %ebx
         movl $(__USER_DS), %edx
         movl %edx, %ds
         movl %edx, %es
         movl $(__KERNEL_PERCPU), %edx
         movl %edx, %fs
         SET_KERNEL_GS %edx
.endm
```

When completed *ESP* will point to the location where the last register was pushed. That address is copied to *EAX* with `movl %esp,%eax`, and *EAX* becomes the pointer for `struct pt_regs *regs` . All the pushed registers on the stack become the actual *pt_regs* data structure, and *EAX* now points to it.

The `asmlinkage` macro will be found in the kernel for those functions that require arguments to be passed on the stack the conventional way. It is defined as something like:

```
#define asmlinkage CPP_ASMLINKAGE __attribute__((regparm(0)))
```

Where `regparm(0)` says that no parameters will be passed via registers.

One really has to know what the build options are, and the version of the kernel being used to make an accurate assessment of the convention being used.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s06.html

> The `SAVE_ALL` macro expands to the following fragment:
>
> ```
> cld
> push %es
> push %ds
> pushl %eax
> pushl %ebp
> pushl %edi
> pushl %esi
> pushl %edx
> pushl %ecx
> pushl %ebx
> movl $ _ _USER_DS,%edx
> movl %edx,%ds
> movl %edx,%es
> ```
>
> After saving the registers, the address of the current top stack location is saved in the `eax` register [with `movl %esp,%eax`, so that ] `eax` points to the stack location containing the last register value pushed on by `SAVE_ALL`

So the `eax` register is the register through which `smp_apic_timer_interrupt` receives the `pt_regs` pointer.

Comment: The source looks like it wants a pointer to where they're stored on the stack, so `eax` makes sense, but neither the question nor answer have said anything about Linux (the kernel) internally using a register-call function ABI even for i386 (not amd64).  Assuming you're correct about why the `mov %esp, %eax` is there, this would be an even better answer if you could link to the kernel docs that explain that.  Otherwise I'd assume that `smp_apic_timer_interrupt` would take the last thing pushed onto the stack (`%ebx`) as its first arg, which makes no sense.

Comment: Linux kernel is built fastcall (eax, ecx, edx).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The Linux kernel actually uses GCC's `regparm` convention on 32-bit x86, specifically `gcc -mregparm=3`, which is EAX, EDX, ECX, in that order, and caller-pops.   MS fastcall `__attribute__((fastcall))` uses only 2 registers, ECX and EDX, and is callee-pops for stack args, unlike `__attribute__((regparm(3)))`.   Apparently Borland's "fastcall" does use EAX, EDX, ECX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Borland_register); presumably that's where GCC got its regparm order from.  But it's also more like stdcall for stack args, unlike regparm.

Comment: TL:DR: using registers or not isn't the only way calling conventions can differ, and "fastcall" is a name used by a few specific calling conventions that pass args in registers, not including GCC's `-mregparm`.  I dislike using it more broadly to describe register-arg conventions in general.